# Mongoose query returns empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a Node.js API endpoint to return some values for population of a select control.

I have the following document in a collection called projectStatusValues...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5cab4b2b38802527df2f7ab2"
  },
  "projectStatusDesc": [
    "Complete",
    "Pre-Start",
    "Active"
  ]
}
```

And my Mongoose model is defined as...

```
const projStatusModel = mongoose.model("projectStatusValues", {
    "projectStatusDesc": [
        String
    ]
});
```

The finally, I'm using this code to retrieve the array values...

```
app.get('/v1/projStatus', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        var status = await projStatusModel.find().exec();
        response.send(status);
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

The endpoint looks good and I get a 200 response but an empty string is returned. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not specifying a project ID by the way. Put a console log on status. It doesn't make sense it would return a string, find does not return strings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't need to return a project ID here. What does find return? I'm expecting JSON which is a string right?

Comment: Find will return an array, with all found documents as javascript objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renamed the collection from projectStatusValues to projectstatusvalues and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `Schema`

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const projStatusModel = mongoose.model("projectStatusValues", new Schema ({
    "projectStatusDesc": [
        String
    ]
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Tried it but still returns and empty string.

I have other API's that seem to work fine without defining a schema, just using model only as with my example. Should I always be defining the schema? What is the consequence of not defining it given that my other API's all work OK without?

Comment: I didn't know that it would work without the schema, but since [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) uses Schema every time, I would suggest to do the same.
I noticed you named the model `projectStatusValues`, and use in your controller as `projStatusModel`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: projectStatusValues is the name of the collection

Comment: I'm naming the model projStatusModel when defining as a constant and when using in the controller.